# Module not found outside of main directory

Tags: node.js, package, dependencies

I have the following dir structure:

```
src/
    app/
        package.json
        node_modules/
        app.js
    tools/
       tool_A.js
```

tool_A.js requires the express package

app.js requires tool_A

I have defined the express package in the requirements for app/package.json and it was correctly installed in the node_modules folder.

The issue is that if I run app/app.js I still get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

Is there a way to make it search the modules starting from the root app, rather than the outside directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `package.json` to the root directory and use `require("../tools/toolA.js")` inside of `app.js`.

Alternatively you create a new package inside of `tools` and install express for that package:

```
.../src/tools> npm init
[...]
.../src/tools> npm i express
```

Given your description, it seems as though the first solution is more appropriate for your situation, but both theoretically work.

**EDIT**:
*Theoretically*, though it's anything but clean, you could also use `require("../app/node_modules/express")`, but that would break as soon as the path to the express module changes.

Comment: I'm using docker, the tools contain several methods used by various applications, not all the methods/classes are used by app.js, that is why I didn't want a separated package.json cause it means I need to install useless packages in the docker image, and in the other way I would mix the packages between all the applications

Comment: @GioGio See my edit. Basically, if you want to use require("express"), you have to use it from a file that's in a package which has express installed. If you want to access express from outside of that package, you are going to need to specify the file path to the node_modules/express folder.